# logstash refresh lookup file when using translate function

Tags: logstash, translate

I have the yml file which I used the "traslate" function to do lookup.

What was done is to translate a string like "superhost.com" to "found".

My problem is that if I were to add in more entries there entries will not be reflected.

For example
I add a "ultrahost.com" entry into the yml file while logstash is still running. Incoming logs with "ultrahost.com" will not be translated to "found". This will only work after I have restarted the logstash script.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `refresh_interval` parameter to the `translate` plugin that can be used to specify how often to re-read the file.  The default is 300 seconds (5 minutes). You can lower that to be whatever interval you think will satisfy how often that the file will be updated.